# sending the value of HTML checkbox to django view

Tags: python, html, django, jenkins

I have the following HTML page

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="1">REG_AGREED_SUITE01
  </label>
   <hr>
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="2">REG_AGREED_SUITE02
  </label>
   <hr>
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="3">REG_AGREED_SUITE03
  </label>
```

I have a Django view like this

```
cd1 = "<command>"
cd2 = "</command>"
test_runner_path = "Abc - C:\git_new\evo_automation\ tests\TestRunner"
test_runner_path2 = "Def - C:\git_new\evo_automation\ tests\TestRunner"
STB = "VMS_01"
TestSuite = "REG_AGREED_SUITE02"
```

Right now I am passing TestSuite value manually from views. But I am trying like, If I select the checkbox from html page, It should replace the hard coded value in views and pass the parameter. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: When you click button `Submit` in form then view will get `request` and `request.POST` with values from form.

Comment: Thank you furas.. Right now I Don't have any form for this. I am Just trying to pass what ever checkbox is selected in html should go into that view in "TestSuite". I found this way TestSuite = request.POST.getlist('checks[]'). But this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery and ajax request to pass data to view:

```
   $("checkbox").change(function(){
        $.post("path/to/url",
        {
            checkBoxValue: $("#CheckboxID").val()
        }
    });
```

Comment: probably OP has no `button` yet. Maybe show how to execute function when checkbox changes value.